# showing that a date is greater than current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I show something in SQL where the date is greater than the current date?

I want to pull out data that shows everything greater from today (now) for the next coming 90 days.

I was thinking `=< {fn NOW()}` but that doesnt seem to work in my sql view here.

How can this be done?

Comment: are you using sql server? my sql?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't seem to work'? Is there a syntax error or does it just not produce the results you want?

Comment: For MySQL (if `field` is datetime): `WHERE (field >= NOW() AND field <= NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY)`. If it's a date field: `WHERE (field >= CUR_DATE() AND field <= CUR_DATE() + INTERVAL 90 DAY)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CreatedDate >= getdate() 
AND CreatedDate <= dateadd(day, 90, getdate())
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Hi! just a small question, how do I get the first date which comes after current date rather than getting all the dates

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a field for `DateTime`, you could have your query look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DateTime > (GetDate() + 90)
```

Answer (score 3):

In sql server, you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.date > DATEADD(dd,90,now())
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that want a nice conditional:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME  = 'some date in future' --example  DateAdd(day,5,GetDate())

IF @MyDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Date NOT greater than today...'
END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'Date greater than today...'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

```
select *
from YourTable
where DateCol between getdate() and dateadd(d, 90, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table where date > 'Today's date(mm/dd/yyyy)'
```

You can also add time in the single quotes(00:00:00AM)

For example:

```
Select * from Receipts where Sales_date > '08/28/2014 11:59:59PM'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server it would be something like this:

```
DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),FUTUREDATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 90
```

Comment: I just tested this to make sure on SQL 2008R2 and it was syntactically correct. SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATEDIFF(d,ImportDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90